# How do I enforce a global column-type using excel_sheet?

Tags: r, dplyr, readxl

I am importing several datasets that needs to be `bind_rows()` afterwards. For this reason, I would like set a global column type for every column of the tbl_df that results from running `excel_sheet()` function.
The reason is that different column types retrieve errors when I `bind_rows()` them.

I was trying `read_excel("myExcel.xlsx", sheet=1, col_types = 'text')` assuming that `text` would have been recycled, but I got an error message saying `read_excel("survey.xlsx", sheet=1, col_types = 'text')`.

Comment: I am not sure why the downgrade. If it's because of mentioning a function in the title, that's simply because I wanna stay in the dplyr envinroment and that function returns `tbl_df()` objects.

Answer (score 0):

My solution has been to mutate after import:

```
res.df <- import.df %>% mutate(col.name = as.character(col.name))
```

Its not the most elegant, as it uses a second operation after the import. But it has worked for me.